# Move forward or backward 4 motors only when a keyboard key is pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a robot car with 4 DC motors and I'm trying to control it from PC with SSH, I can't find anything how cand I make the robot to move forward only when the button on the keyboard is pressed,

This is the code that I created, it is not that complicated but from what I've found, this is what I created, and for now, the car mover forward, backward, left and right but when I press 'a' to go to the left it rotates very fast and I want to rotate only when the key is pressed and when it's depressed tot stop and to do this for each direction.

I  tried to import keyboard and when I run the program in terminal it tells me that "No module named keyboard." 
If someone can help me I would appreciate that,

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import curses
import keyboard


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(31,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(33,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(35,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(37,GPIO.OUT)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)

try:
    while True:
        char = screen.getch()
        if char == ord('q'):
            break
        if keyboard.is_pressed('w'): #move forward all 4 motors(11,15,31,35)
            GPIO.output(11,True)
            GPIO.output(13,False)
            GPIO.output(15,True)
            GPIO.output(16,False)
            GPIO.output(31,True)
            GPIO.output(33,False)
            GPIO.output(35,True)
            GPIO.output(37,False)
            break

        elif char == ord('s') : #move backword all 4 motors(13,16,33,37)
            GPIO.output(11,False)
            GPIO.output(13,True)
            GPIO.output(15,False)
            GPIO.output(16,True)
            GPIO.output(31,False)
            GPIO.output(33,True)
            GPIO.output(35,False)
            GPIO.output(37,True)

        elif char == ord('a'): #move left(2 motors forward and 2 backward)
            GPIO.output(11,False)
            GPIO.output(13,True)
            GPIO.output(15,True)
            GPIO.output(16,False)
            GPIO.output(31,True)
            GPIO.output(33,False)
            GPIO.output(35,False)
            GPIO.output(37,True)

        elif char == ord('d'): # oposite from left to go right
            GPIO.output(11,True)
            GPIO.output(13,False)
            GPIO.output(15,False)
            GPIO.output(16,True)
            GPIO.output(31,False)
            GPIO.output(33,True)
            GPIO.output(35,True)
            GPIO.output(37,False)


        elif char == 10: # stop all the motors
            GPIO.output(11,False)
            GPIO.output(11,False)
            GPIO.output(15,False)
            GPIO.output(15,False)
            GPIO.output(31,False)
            GPIO.output(31,False)
            GPIO.output(35,False)
            GPIO.output(35,False)

finally:
    curses.nocbreak(); screen.keypad(0); curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Please put code in a text entry here, not as images.

Comment: Are you sure you installed `keyboard` on the system running your script? Maybe you need to run `pip install keyboard`?

Comment: Yes it is installed and i also runed it as root and doesn't work.... when i press 'w' it appears something about keyboard and at the end tells me : " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' "

Comment: Can you please add the full traceback to your post? And also the message that comes up about keyboard when you press "w"

Comment: There's a `break` at the end of your "w" portion, which will break out of the loop and have your code jump to the `finally` clause. Is this intended?

Comment: I changed that and now it doesn't give ne any errors or something. When i start the program all the motors turnes on and when i press 'w' stops and nothing works anymore, only if i restart the program and does the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your question, but a suggestion to avoid many many copy-pasted operations throughout your code. It also helps with readability.

Now hopefully we can identify more easily where the error comes from.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import curses
import keyboard
OUTPUTS = (11, 13, 15, 16, 31, 33, 35, 37) # Define the outputs you'll use as a "constant".

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
for output in OUTPUTS:
    GPIO.setup(output, GPIO.OUT) # A for loop replaces 8 copy-pasted lines.

def set_outputs_states(byte_string):
    for n, char in enumerate(byte_string): # Read e.g. "00001111" character by character.
        output = OUTPUTS[n]                # n-th character is linked to the n-th output.
        state = bool(char)                 # Change "0" or "1" into False or True.
        GPIO.output(output, state)         # Turn the selected output on or off.

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)

try:
    while True:
        char = screen.getch()

        if char == ord('q'):
            break

        if keyboard.is_pressed('w'): #move forward all 4 motors(11,15,31,35)
            set_outputs_states("10101010") # Functions help reducing the size of your code.
            break

        elif char == ord('s') : #move backword all 4 motors(13,16,33,37)
            set_outputs_states("01010101")

        elif char == ord('a'): #move left(2 motors forward and 2 backward)
            set_outputs_states("01101001")

        elif char == ord('d'): # oposite from left to go right
            set_outputs_states("10010110")

        elif char == 10: # stop all the motors
            set_outputs_states("00000000")

finally:
    curses.nocbreak()
    screen.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```